# Add/Edit Columns in DataBound DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a datagridview that is databound from a database table.  How do I:

a) Edit the displayed value for a column using the values from other columns in the row?  (For example, display a URL like:

```
    <a href="/url?param=columnA">columnB</a>
```

where columnA is the value from column A and columnB is the value from columnB)

b) Add an additional column using values from the other columns (similar to a.)

Answer (score 0):

[You could add a DataColumn that uses an Expression to the DataTable.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you've already tried, but for a) you could try [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event, for b) [How to: Add an Unbound Column to a Data-Bound Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkatshfa.aspx)